# python match.group() but not mmatched

Tags: python, regex

i meet re.match questions when learning python 
code the following :

`def pythonReSubDemo():
   inputstr='hello 111'
   def add(matched):
      intvalue=matched.group(0)
      ...
   re.sub('\d+',add,inputstr)`

there not use match to matched any regular expression why can use match.group()

Comment: Fix your formatting please.

Comment: Use `intvalue=matched.group(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex groups are in round brackets:

```
re.sub('(\d+)',add,inputstr)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mB6cS8/1)

Comment: There is no point in the capturing group as the match value is stored in `.group(0)`

Answer (score 0):

To name a group use following syntax:

```
(?P<number> ... )
```

---

```
re.sub('(?P<number>\d+)', add, inputstr)
```

---

```
>>> def add(matched):
...     return str(int(matched.group('number')) + 1)
... 
>>> inputstr='hello 111'
>>> re.sub('(?P<number>\d+)', add, inputstr)
'hello 112'
```

Comment: thanks  this matched  equivalent to match('\d+',inputstr) ?

Comment: `\d+`, not `\d`. and the matched group can be accessed using the group name `number`: `matched.group('number')`

Comment: i mean i want  kow this keyword(args) matched  not use match func ,why can i use match.group()

Comment: @firstg, If you mean `re.match`, it matches only at the beginning of the string, you maybe want to use `re.search()`.  `re.search(r'\d+', input_string).group()`

Comment: this matched just a regx name not re.match ?

Comment: @firstg, Sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean 'regex name'?